# Crossover missing pygtk

Tags: crossover

So i installed Crossover how it said on their site

I installed crossover because Wine isn't so good so i installed it and i searched up Crossover in the search bar and i got this
[image]

I enter my Root password then it does all kind of stuff and at the end it says this 
[image]

I press enter and it just does this 
[image]

I've looked up how to install both of those errors but i got none and if i tried installing pythong-gtk2 it says its installed but Crossover asks me for the same thing over and over and won't download

I tried everything but can't get it to work does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I get the same error